# Bus in sensitivity list in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

Is it possible to evaluate statements in an always block when *any* bit in a bus is toggled(posedge)? e.g. If I have:

```
input [1:0] a;
always@([what to do here?]) begin
  [statements]
end
```

I have tried

```
always@(posedge a)
```

and also

```
always@(posedge a[1:0])
```

but simulation shows only on posedge of a[0] are the statements evaluated.

I am not able to use "," or "or" because the width is determined by a parameter. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a process for each bit

```
event ev;
for （genvar ii =0;ii<$bits(a);ii++) begin 
   always  @(posedge a[ii] ) ->>ev;
end 
always @ev ...
```